# When walking through files and folders, how do I compare the current filename with the next, in python?

Tags: python, directory

I'm running a script that runs through folders and files and use these very simple loops. Now I was wondering how I could compare the current filename with the one that comes next, within this loop?

```
list_of_files = {}
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(path):
        for filename in filenames:
           print 'I know here I could print: ', filename
           print 'but how could I print: ', filename+1
```

Generally, what I want to accomplish is to compare the two files, select one on certain criteria, compare with the next in the same folder on these criteria - until the end of the folder. In the next folder I would like to do the same again.

Comment: Do you want to end up choosing just a single file in each directory, or do you want a pairwise iteration?

Comment: What do you think you mean by "next"?  What order do you think these "should" be in?

Comment: The eventual goal is to select a single file from a directory, taking out all other, with some exceptions possibly left in the folder. Order is irrelevant. It's about comparison between two files and there aren't that many files that it matters to sort them properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be able to extend this to do what you want:

```
>>> for a, b in zip(range(10), range(10)[1:]):
...     print a, b
```

like this:

```
for filename, next in zip(filenames, filenames[1:]):
    print filename, next
```

Edit: I forgot about [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html).

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)
```

Comment: Nice way. But is there a way to use slicing without creating a copy? Some kind of iterslice?

Answer (score 1):

Builtin `enumerate` function numerates an iterable and returns (pos, item) tuples. You can use that.

```
for pos, filename in enumerate(filenames):
    print 'I know here I could print: ', filename
    try:
         print 'but now I could print: ', filenames[pos+1]
    except IndexError:
         #there is no next item
         pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing to the next file, you could accomplish the same thing by comparing to the previous file:

```
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(path):
    lastfile = None  # Will be non-None if last file matched criterion
    for filename in filenames:
       if lastfile and criterion2(lastfile, filename):
          # do something
       lastfile = filename if criterion1(filename) else None
```

Comment: Except that you need to combine `dirpath` and `filename` in this example to find the file.  If `dirpath` isn't encoded into `lastfile`, you don't actually know anything about `lastfile`.

Comment: Well, you know the filename. If the criteria are something like the file extension, then you don't need to know `dirpath`. If you need to actually examine the file, however, you're absolutely right.